# CD to a directory and issue a shell command using GNOME TERMINAL command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, gnome

I have a folder **Parent folder** which contains a script **mytestcase.sh**

```
parent_folder/mytestcase.sh
```

I am in Home directory .How can I start a new terminal using GNOME TERMINAL command, CD to parent_folder and issue the above script.
The output of a new terminal should CD to Parent_folder and later issue the mytestcase.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following:

```
gnome-terminal --window --working-directory /full/path/to/parent_folder -- ./mytestcase.sh
```

If you want to keep the terminal open after execution of `mytestcase.sh` ends:

Method 1. Modify your `mytestcase.sh` script to add at the end a command like:

```
read DUMMY
```

This will wait until you press ENTER and then the terminal window will close.

Method 2. Use a custom profile in GNOME Terminal. In Preferences, define a new profile (let's call it `noclose`) and in the "Command" tab, choose the option to keep the window open after the command finishes. Then call `gnome-terminal` with the following command:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=noclose --working-directory /full/path/to/parent_folder -- ./mytestcase.sh
```

Comment: The above command closes the terminal immediately after execution. How can we keep the terminal alive and check for the mytestcase.sh output?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include this.